# Append values to an empty PANDAS dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have created an empty dataframe and I have also named the columns, I didn't specify any index:

```
  columns = ['C1','C2']
  emp=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
```

I want to populate the emp dataframe with the output I get from a for loop. For example:

```
  j=0
  for i in iset:
      emp[j]["C1"]=i
      emp[j]["C2"]=i*i
```

So, as a result, assuming iset is 2, 3, 4 I would like to have:

```
           C1   C2                      
   index
   1       2    4
   2       3    9
   3       4    16
```

How could I do it? Any suggestions are welcome, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally very inefficient to append to a dataframe in that manner, as it returns a new copy of the dataframe each time resulting in quadratic copying.  You would be better off creating the columns as variables, and then using them to create your dataframe.

```
iset = [2, 3, 4]
c1 = []
c2 = []
for i in iset:
    c1.append(i)
    c2.append(i * i)

emp = pd.DataFrame({'C1': c1, 'C2': c2})

>>> emp
   C1  C2
0   2   4
1   3   9
2   4  16
```

**Timings**

```
%%timeit
iset = range(1000)
emp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['C1', 'C2'])
for i in iset:
    emp = emp.append({'C1': i, 'C2': i * i}, ignore_index=True)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.79 s per loop

%%timeit
iset = range(1000)
c1 = []
c2 = []
for i in iset:
    c1.append(i)
    c2.append(i * i)

emp = pd.DataFrame({'C1': c1, 'C2': c2})
1000 loops, best of 3: 779 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both the suggestion about creating columns and also for providing the solution and also for the promptness.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
>>> iset
[2, 3, 4]

>>> pd.DataFrame({'C1': iset, 'C2': map(lambda x: x*x, iset)})
   C1  C2
0   2   4
1   3   9
2   4  16
```

Comment: It works too, thank you very much, the lambda approach is elegant, haven't thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you want your `df` to be filled row-by-row with a `for` loop the following will do:

```
emp=pd.DataFrame(columns=['C1','C2'])
iset = [2,3,4]

for i,j in enumerate(iset):
    emp.loc[i] = [j, j*j]

emp
    C1  C2
0   2.0 4.0
1   3.0 9.0
2   4.0 16.0
```

Comment: I tried it and also works, thank you for the prompt reply.